# can any one know how to import this Quilt View project in my eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Can any one know how to import this Quilt View project in eclipse? The link will guide u to the project, https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try File > Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace from the Eclipse main menu.

Comment: Do u think, I didnt try importing the project. I Imported the project and there are two main activity, so i Renamed the first mainactivity. atlast i successfully imported. But my question is, 1. I dont know which one is the library and the program. 2. I just need a sample program to run this quiltview project, so can anyone write a sample program for me using this quilt view?

Comment: @baskar: "I dont know which one is the library and the program" -- the `res/` and `src/` and such in the top-level directory represent the library. "I just need a sample program to run this quiltview project" -- the `sample/QuiltViewSample/` directory in the top-level directory points to a sample project.

Comment: Atlast i solve the issue in quiltview, f follow this link below, u will get the sample program to run the quiltview, link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_1ciqoQIcQ&hd=1 . Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one MainActivity declared in Manifest file so that must be the main Launcher.